# Do Errant and Giada and Rattlechains allow me to cast Spirits with flying from my library at instant speed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Errant and Giada](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=607282) allows you to cast creatures with flying from your library.
[Rattlechains](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=606701) allows you to cast Spirits as though they had flash.

If I have both Errant and Giada and Rattlechains on the battlefield, can I cast Spirits with flying from my library at instant speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can cast Spirits with flying at instant speed with those cards in play.**

The two cards' modifications work independently from each other, and each modify a different rule - [Errant and Giada](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Errant%20and%20Giada) allows you to cast spells with flying (among others) from the top of your library, and [Rattlechains](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rattlechains) allows you to cast Spirit spells (without any additional qualifier such as "from your hand") as thought they had flash. With both abilities in play, you can cast Spirit spells with flying from the top of your library as thought they had flash.