# Do Errant and Giada and Rattlechains allow me to cast Spirits without flying or flash from my library?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Very similar to the related question: *[Do Errant and Giada and Rattlechains allow me to cast Spirits with flying from my library at instant speed?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/58814/39900)* That question deals with Spirits with flying, while this question deals with spirits *without* flying.

[Errant and Giada](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Errant%20and%20Giada) allows you to cast spells with flash from the top of your library.
[Rattlechains](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rattlechains) allows you to cast spirits as though they had flash.

Does a spirit benefitting from Rattlechains' ability cause it to also benefit from Errant and Giada's ability, and allow it to be cast from the library even though it did not have flash or flying naturally?

Comment: i think the issue here is the rattlechain effect: which changes how you, the player, can cast things but because it does not cause spirits to change their properties, they don't have 'flash' -> errant & giada condition not satisfied -> no casting from top of library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, this combination of cards will not allow you to cast Spirits without flying or flash from the top of your library.**

[Rule 609.4](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Effect) says

> Some effects state that a player may do something “as though” some condition were true or a creature can do something “as though” some condition were true. This applies only to the stated effect. **For purposes of that effect, treat the game exactly as if the stated condition were true. For all other purposes, treat the game normally.**

Rattlechains ability "You may cast Spirit spells as though they had flash" applies only to determining when you can cast Spirit spells. It does not extend to evaluating the condition on Errant and Giada's ability.

---

In contrast, if you controlled [Teferi, Mage of Zhalfir](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Teferi%2C%20Mage%20of%20Zhalfir), along with Errant and Giada, you would be able to cast any creature spell from the top of your library.

Comment: Giving it Flash without giving it Flash.

Comment: So I'm not sure this answer is correct, because of the "For purposes of that effect, treat the game exactly as if the stated condition were true" clause. 

My reasoning is that in both cases the "effect" in question is casting. That is I'm seeing the effect play out like this 1) I try to cast the card from the top of the library 2) errant and giada checks to see if it has flash or flying, and because of rattlechains ability for the purpose of casting the spirit, we treat it as if it does

Comment: @JamesJackson I am asserting in my answer that "that effect" in this instance is determining **when** you can cast the spell and not the whole process of determining **whether** you can cast the spell. I don't have a direct justification for that, but every other ruling I can find online matches what I said.

Comment: @mergatroid99 I thought the specific nuance of the casting procedure might come into play here, and I just found this "601.3b If an effect allows a player to cast a spell with certain qualities as though it had flash, that player may consider any choices to be made during that spell’s proposal that may cause that spell’s qualities to change. If any such choices could cause that effect to apply, that player may begin to cast that spell as though it had flash" and since the proposal step is the first step in casting (601.2) I think this does allow the casting non flash from the top of library

Comment: @mergatroid99 this passage seems to have been written to clarify how effects like Rattlechains affect timing restrictions, so I could see how reasonable minds could disagree. But I think a plain reading does allow casting here

Comment: @mergatorid99 okay it looks like you are correct. In the "that effect" clause "that effect" refers to flash itself. So it's saying that the effect of flash works, rather than saying other effects dependent on the card having flash will treat it as if it has flash. I think the passage I found could then also be read in a similar way. Source: comments section of https://youtu.be/hiygmEjT5r8?si=FibE-DNg-vj58XtW

Comment: 601.3b is not relevant here. It is talking about effects like on Harbinger of the Tides, which says "You may cast Harbinger of the Tides as though it had flash if you pay {2} more to cast it." Even though you don't choose what additional costs to pay until step 601.2b, 601.3b allows you to start casting it at instant speed.